# Input Password box before making all sheets visible

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to try to implement an input box for the user to enter a password before the code runs to make all sheets visible.

The code below is within `ThisWorkbook` and I would like to add the code here for an input box to pop up and the user to enter the password from a preset password

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("Contents").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    MsgBox "Please refer to user guide for any help", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "PRODUCT BIBLE"
```

Comment: Why not just password protect the workbook?

Comment: Valid point however I couldn't do this as Excel wouldnt let me. "This workbook contains Excel 4.0 Macros or Excel 5.0 Modules If you would like to password protect or restrict permission you need to remove these macros" 
So below was the workaround

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone but I managed to work this through, the user will have to enter a password to open up all the worksheets. If they don't it will loop back until the password is right (probably could be cleaned up but it works).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strName As String     
    Do Until strName = "Bible"
        strName = InputBox("Enter the Password:", "Password")
        On Error Resume Next
        If strName = "Bible" Then
            MsgBox "Correct Password", vbInformation
            On Error GoTo 0
        ElseIf strName = False Then MsgBox "You have entered the incorrect password ", vbInformation
        End If
    Loop

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("Contents").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "Please refer to user guide for any help", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "PRODUCT BIBLE"
End Sub
```

Comment: And just suppose you forget your password?  Open it, do not put the right password in and try to close it.

Comment: Good point - Just tried it and there is no way of closing it without the right password,  I guess the user will have to close Excel somehow from task manager... or just make sure they remember the password.

Comment: You could change "Enter the Password:" to something like "Enter the Password or type ""Close"" to exit:", then close Excel if strName = "Close"  (just an idea for modifying the existing setup)

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful!! Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would put password protection on the file:

Goto the file tab, hit protect workbook then encrypt with password.

(May vary depending on Excel version)

See for more details.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-documents-workbooks-and-presentations-ef163677-3195-40ba-885a-d50fa2bb6b68

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I believe is cleaner and also more secure against a user committed to accessing data they shouldn't, is to have your workbook attempt to pull in the confidential data from a read-only file in a shared network location, to which only limited users have access.

This puts security outside of your hands and onto IT, meaning it is more secure, more flexible [to add a new user, no need to add in the passwords manually, just have that person added to the list of users able to access the network drive], and avoids problems as you state above, like forcing the user to use the task manager to close Excel if they forget a password. In fact, users don't need to enter a password at all, so the user experience is more friendly as well.